# gem compass install fails on OS X 10.11

Tags: compass, osx-elcapitan

Running: `sudo gem install compass`

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/compass
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me (no idea why):
danielgolden @ https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/2018

1. `brew install ruby`
2. `sudo gem update --system`
3. `sudo gem install compass`